# Python - how to return a value from a class AFTER user interaction

Tags: python, user-interface, pyside, pyside2

I've a python question, could be very simple but I have no idea how to do it.
Basically I want to run:

```
value = myUiClass().getValue()
```

If I run the following, it will return None directly and not event wait for the user to interact with a UI (that I haven't defined here as the UI itself is not the point)

```
class MyUi(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyUi, self).__init__(parent)

        self.finalValue = None

        # UI that will modify self.finalValue

    def getValue(self):
        return self.finalValue

value = MyUi().getValue()
```

I guess I'am missing something to pause the process until the user interacts with the UI ?

Here is an example of what I want

```
from PySide2 import QtWidgets
col = QtWidgets.QColorDialog.getColor()
print col
```

Any idea ?

Thx

Comment: What's the problem you have exactly? Please show a [mcve]. Python has many, many UI frameworks. What are you using?

Comment: I ve edited the initial post with more info

Comment: To obtain the data before an event you have to use signals and slots, that is a basic task in pyside and I think you can get it in any basic tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after looking more in depth. Using QDialog is easier since it has a built-in method for that.

**exec_()** will pause the process until it gets an answer from the dialog (**self.accept()** or **self.reject()**)

It is apparently possible to do it with a QWidget too but the procedure is a bit different and I haven't tested it. You can actually find the explanation in the QDialog reference.

```
from PySide2 import QtWidgets

class MyDialog(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyDialog, self).__init__(parent)

        self.valueToReturn = None

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        super(MyDialog, self).mousePressEvent(event)
        # get the value from UI and set it here
        self.valueToReturn = 5
        self.accept()

    @staticmethod
    def launch():
        dlg = MyDialog()
        r = dlg.exec_()
        if r:
            return dlg.valueToReturn
        else:
            return None

value = MyDialog.launch()
print value
```